# Jar or a Flat file for a writing a word web like java Application

Tags: java, database

I am writing a application similar to Word Web. For this Purpose, I need English Dictionary in a Jar file or Flat file format.

Is there a Jar file in Java with a English dictionary words in it? Or Is there any flat file or DB file available to get the words and Values into a HashMap?

Any help is very much Appreciated... 
Thanks!

Comment: i'll be interested in the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a shot in the dark, but if you're on a unix / linux system you have access to

```
/usr/share/dict/words
```

which is a pretty extensive list if you ask me.

Maybe you can read the file and build whatever data structure you need out of it??

Comment: Thank you... i am able to find the list of words in Linux Box... is there  any location where the meanings to these words are stored ...

Comment: The meanings might be difficult to obtain :(